# convert sql query to array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, split

I have try for days, to make my query row as array but haven't success yet. 
I have 'cat.1','cat.2','cat.3','cat.4','cat.5','cat.1','cat.2','cat.3','cat.4','cat.5' in mysql row and want to make this as array so i will get 10 array rather than 1. 
Next i will use it to combine with another row that has same pattern. Look like this 0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))  
  {  
    $keys = Array($row['listcat']);
    $values = Array($row['rightval']);
    $final_array [$row['testid']]= array_combine_($keys, $values);
  }
```

my function array_combine_ i get from [here](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-combine.php)

```
function array_combine_($keys, $values){
    $result = array();

    foreach ($keys as $i => $k) {
     $result[$k][] = $values[$i];
     }

    array_walk($result, function(&$v){
     $v = (count($v) == 1) ? array_pop($v): $v;
     });

    return $result;
}
```

I always get one array rather than ten, so its can't be combine two arrays. What i want the result is like this

```
[8131] => Array ( 
  [cat.1] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 ) 
  [cat.2] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 ) 
  [cat.3] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 ) 
  [cat.4] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 ) 
  [cat.5] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 ) 
)
[8173] => Array ( 
  [cat.1] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 ) 
  [cat.2] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 ) 
  [cat.3] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 )
  [cat.4] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 ) 
  [cat.5] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 ) 
)
```

Comment: Where you take `Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 )`, etc.? What I see is VERY bad SQL table schema

Comment: Can you var_dump a row and show the output of that for an example so we can tell for sure what's in the table? And could you show an example of the output you're currently getting instead of what you're trying to get? (Sorry, got that backward at first)

Comment: thanks for your comments, i use this for my a simply way..

Comment: var_dump($keys) = "'KD.1','KD.2','KD.3','KD.4','KD.5','KD.1','KD.2','KD.3','KD.4','KD.5'"

Comment: var_dump($values) = "0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0"

Comment: I hope you meant 'column', not 'row'! :-(

Comment: if i use $keys = Array('KD.1','KD.2','KD.3','KD.4','KD.5','KD.1','KD.2','KD.3','KD.4','KD.5'); and 
    $values = Array(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0); i get what i want.

Comment: what meant column and not row...? mr @Strawberry

Comment: You don't need to write your own `array_combine()` function, it's built into PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array($row['listkd'])` will not parse the string as separate array elements. It just creates an array with a single element, which is the entire contents of the `listkd` column.

You can use `str_getcsv()` to parse the string. It will split it on the commas, and parse the quotes as delimiters around the values.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))  
  {  
    $keys = str_getcsv($row['listkd'], ",", "'");
    $values = str_getcsv($row['rightval'], ",", "'");

    $final_array [$row['testnis']]= array_combine_($keys, $values);
  }
```

Comment: He could use [str_getcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) to parse the CSV strings - it'll strip all the quotes, separators and create an array all at once.

Comment: @ReddHerring Good idea, didn't think of that shortcut.